# convert a python code with function structure to class structure with generator and calculate time and space complexity

Tags: python, generator

I wrote this simple python code but now I have to convert this into a `class` structure which accepts an iterator and act as a generator to yield the tuples(instead of return it should yield). I am unable to convert it:

```
    def func(str,size):

        size1 = size
        list1 = []

        for i in str:
            list1.append(i)

            if len(list1) < size1:
                return (0)
                continue
            if len(list) > win_size1:
                list1.pop(0)      

            min = min(list1)

            return (min)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    str = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    size = [4]
    res = sol2(str,size)
```

Also I have to get the time and space complexity. In my view time complexity looks O(n)(I am not 100% confident though) but I am unable to determine space complexity.

How can I convert this code into a class with generator and what would be the time and space complexity?

Comment: WTF? Why have you completely changed the code? This is a completely different algorithm to that originally presented, and it includes new bugs. Changing the code of your question invalidates all answers given so far.

Comment: @mhawke I had to make changes as the requirement changed. I apologise

Comment: Then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the `continue` statements which follow the `return` statements make no sense - `continue` will never be reached. However, you can *yield* each tuple with `yield` instead of `return`, e.g., replace

```
return (None,None,None,None)
```

with

```
yield (None,None,None,None)
```

Now the `continue` statement can actually be executed, and your algorithm can return more than one tuple.

Simply changing the returns into yields makes your function a generator.

I don't see any necessity to make this a "class structure". You can create a class and make `sol2()` a method of that class, but it's not clear why you should want to do that.

Comment: And what would be my time and space complexity?

Comment: @user2966197: What do you think?  When it had `return` statements it was O(1). I'm not really sure what your algorithm is trying to do, but with the `yield` statements it looks O(n) to me.

Comment: It's not O(n^2) if that's what you're thinking. You can argue that it is _2n_, but that is the same as _n_ so far as complexity goes. So O(n) for both.

Answer (score 0):

only the window1 and window2 will ask for extra space, so I think the space complexity will be O(n).